# How can I build variants of an executable with one makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have one set of source files from which I need to generate multiple variants of an executable. For example I need to generate **app1.elf**, **app2.elf**, **app3.elf** from the same **main.c** and **comm.c**.  The difference between each of the apps is a node address, a parameter that is passed down in the invocation of gcc. i.e.:

```
gcc -DNODE=1 -oapp1.elf main.c 
gcc -DNODE=2 -oapp2.elf main.c 
gcc -DNODE=3 -oapp3.elf main.c
```

Let's assume that I have the following files:

- src/main.c
- src/comm.c

When I run the Makefile as so:

> make all_nodes

make only builds app1.elf with the following output:

> Built app1
>   Built app2
>   Built app3

**FAIL!**
The output seems to suggest that it worked, however it only generates one executable, namely app1.elf.  Anybody care to point out what I'm doing wrong?

To further explain my Makefile, I've created a *cleanobjs* target to clean out the objects in the ./obj subdirectory.  This is my attempt at having 'make' rebuild the obj files with the new **node** address, but it fails.  Am I using 'make' in a way it wasn't intended to be used?  I know I can also create a batch file to run make (something I've done sucessfully) but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. My  Makefile is below:

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c
    gcc -DNODE=$(NODE) -o$@ $<

app.elf : ./obj/main.o ./obj/comm.o
    gcc -oapp$(NODE).elf main.o comm.o

node1 : NODE=1
node1 : cleanobj app.elf
    @echo 'Built app1'

node2 : NODE=2
node2 : cleanobj app.elf
    @echo 'Built app2'

node3 : NODE=3
node3 : cleanobj app.elf
    @echo 'Built app3'

all_nodes : node1 node2 node3

cleanobj :
    rm -rf obj/main.o obj/comm.o

.PHONY : cleanobj
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that the reasons this is failing is because make only runs a target once per instance.  So both cleanobj and app.elf get built for the node1 target and for node2 and node3 targets it is optimized out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
SRC     = src/main.c
OBJ     = $(patsubst src%,obj$(VERSION)%,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC)))

C_FLAGS = -DNODE=$(VERSION)


all:    app.1 app.2 app.3

#
# For each application just call make with VERSION set correctly    
app.%:  dir.%
    $(MAKE) VERSION=$* app$*.elf

#
# Build each applications objects into a seprate directory
# So we need to make sure the obj directory exists.    
dir.%:
    @- if ! test -e obj$*; then mkdir obj$*; fi

app%.elf:   $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o$@ $(C_FLAGS) $(OBJ)


obj$(VERSION)/%.o:  src/%.c
    $(CC) -c -o obj$(VERSION)/$*.o $(C_FLAGS) $<
```

Comment: Worked!  It is similar to the solution posted by @Achille below, but this one is more general.  I like.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're going to need multiple targets for the different versions.  Each target is going to need its own main.o and comm.o targets as well, meaning you need to call them something else or they'll end up confusing with each other.  Then your all should function to build all three.

Comment: In addition to that, you also may want to use subdirectories - if you want your applications to be named all the same, there has to be some (other) way to differentiate them.

Comment: @foo, The directory is part of the full file name.

Comment: @AProgrammer yes, but the target name(s) are what is matched. So if you really want to use the same target name, at least have the executables built into separate subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

a similar approach:

```
ifeq ($(NODE),)

all:
    make NODE=1
    make NODE=2
    make NODE=3

cleanobj:
    make NODE=1 cleanobj
    make NODE=2 cleanobj
    make NODE=3 cleanobj

else

OBJS = main.o comm.o
objs = $(patsubst %.o,obj/$(NODE)/%.o,$(OBJS))

app$(NODE).elf: $(objs)
    gcc -o app$(NODE).elf $^
    @echo 'Built app$(NODE)'

obj/$(NODE)/%.o: src/%.c
    gcc -c -DNODE=$(NODE) -o $@ $<

cleanobj :
    rm -rf $(objs)

endif

.PHONY: all cleanobj
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to make separate build directories and use `VPATH` to allow your (mostly unmodified) Makefile to build the original sources in the separate directory.

The slightly harder way is to modify your Makefile to rewrite target `.o` and executable files to be in a subdirectory.  For example:

```
NODE = 1
OBJDIR = obj.node$(NODE)
SRC = main.c comm.o
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
```

Then your targets re-invoke your Makefile with `NODE` set.

Answer (score 0):

create a batch file or shell script which can create all three builds. Something like:

```
make node1
<if needed copy your executable to a different directory>
<clean all objs from make node1>
make node2
<if needed copy your executable to a different directory>
<clean all objs from make node1>
make node3
<if needed copy your executable to a different directory>
<clean all objs from make node1>
```

Call this batch file or shell script for `all_node` build rule.